# How to read header values in spring batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

Hi currently i have a input xml file. I have to read the xml file and write it to another xml file.I need to have output file should have the same headers as the input file

Input file :

```
<testFile>
<fileId>string</fileId>
<fileDate>2008-09-29</fileDate>
<fileTime>01:18:33</fileTime>
<sourceSystemId>string</sourceSystemId>
<Delivery>
    <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
    <deliveryOrder>
       <consumer>
       </consumer>
       <Data>
       </Datla>
    </deliveryOrder>
<Delivery>
<Delivery>
    <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
    <deliveryOrder>
       <consumer>
       </consumer>
       <Data>
       </Datla>
    </deliveryOrder>
<Delivery>
<recordCount>2</recordCount>
 </testFile>
```

Expected output :

```
<testFile>
<fileId>string</fileId>
<fileDate>2008-09-29</fileDate>
<fileTime>01:18:33</fileTime>
<sourceSystemId>string</sourceSystemId>
<conusmers>
    <!--1 r more repetitions:-->
       <consumer>
       </consumer>
        <consumer>
       </consumer>
        <consumer>
       </consumer>
</consumers>

<recordCount>2</recordCount>
 </testFile>
```

I am reading rootElement as Deliveryobject. which doesnt have header tags like fileId,FileName,FileTime. How to get headers in output xml file.

Appreciate your help on this.

Comment: Did you find a way to solve this problem? I need to implement something similar. I am thinking if there is any way to store the header data in jobContext, so that it could be accessed in CustomHeaderCallback.

Answer (score 0):

In your `FlatFileItemWriter` you can call `setHeaderCallback(new StringHeaderWriter("YourHeader"));`

Comment: mrkernelpanic , i dont want to compare the headers. I want to have output file headers same as input headers. How the reader/writer should be configured to read and write headers

Comment: Mrkernelpanic, How we are going to pass the values to headerCallback, how we are going to read the header values to pass it to the headercallback.I want to have header values also the same.